# Object and Parent move separate from each other

Tags: modeling, parent

before I begin I would like to say that I am new to blender so please be patient with my lack of knowledge.
[image]

I want to make a donut to learn the basics of Blender,so far is good,but when it comes to parenting I don't know if either my model is so badly made or maybe there are some values that are not the right.

[image]

One object moves faster then the other and.I would apreciate any advice.
Thank you for your time

Comment: it looks like you've enabled the Proportional Editing option (blue circle icon on the top header menu), it may be your problem

Comment: Yes,this was the problem :)))
Thank you!